# Create a Mathematica function that can be called from R or Matlab

Tags: compile, matlab, rlink

I would like to export a function from Mathematica to allow it to be accessed from R and/or Matlab.

Is there a way to do this?

As an example, suppose I want to export the following (albeit contrived) function, that could be hard to replicate in R:

```
f[x_Integer] := Prime[x]
```

The actual function is long-winded, and its details don't matter (I think, but let me know if you need these). Basically I want to avoid trying to code up something that took me ages in Mathematica, into R or Matlab.

The reason I want to do this is I am writing a class problem set, and I want students (using Matlab or R) to be able to call a function that I have created in Mathematica.

Best,

Ben

Comment: If the function is not computational intense, maybe you could use `CloudDeploy` to create a web API.

Answer (score 9):

As @xslittlegrass suggested in the comments, you could use `CloudDeploy[]`.

The `APIFunction[]` makes it easy to accept input parameters and return the evaluation results of a function. Then you could use `urlread()` in Matlab to query/read answers. Here is an example for the `Prime[x]` case.

First in Mathematica (adapted from the [`APIFunction` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html)):

```
func = APIFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, Prime[#x] &];
api = CloudDeploy[func, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

This will return a `CloudObject` with a URL that looks like "[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/*alphanumericsequence*](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/_alphanumericsequence_)"

Then we can define a m-file function in Matlab:

```
 function [out]=primeAPI(x)
    if ~isnumeric(x) || mod(x,1)~=0
        error('input must be an integer')
    end

    fullURL = ['https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/alphanumericsequence'...
        ,'?x=',num2str(x)];
    apiResponse=urlread(fullURL);
    out=str2num(apiResponse);
```

Running, `primeAPI(100)` from the Matlab command line then returns the number `541`

BTW, I kept getting a network connection error in Matlab when I used the original *"https"* protocol in the URL, so I switched to *"http"* protocol in the m-file URL (as this is public anyway and doesn't require any logins).

Comment: That's great - I will try this later. Many thanks. Just wondering - is there any way this could be called from R? Best, Ben

Comment: @ben18785, I don't use R much but you should be able to use either scan or read commands to get data in from a URL. Maybe [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220/access-a-url-and-read-data-with-r) will help.

Comment: Thanks Rashid, much appreciated. Best, Ben