# TaskWait, SocketObject, and WolframScript

Tags: scripting, asynchronous-processing, socket

I want to launch an asynchronous task with Wolfram Script to listen to a socket and print back information in the CLI. This was handled in previous versions by ``` ZeroMQLink``Private``$AsyncState["Task"] ``` but this doesn't appear to work with my version (13, Win 11 x64).

Minimal Working Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)
Quiet@DeleteObject[listener];

listener = SocketListen[
  3000,
  Function[{assoc},
   With[{client = assoc["SourceSocket"], data = assoc["Data"]},
    request = 
     ImportString[data, "HTTPRequest"]["Query"] /. {"name" -> n_} :> n;
    origin = Association[ request["Headers"] ]["origin"];
    If[ Head[origin] === Missing, origin = "" ];
response = ExportString[
  HTTPResponse[
   ExportString[<|"msg" -> "Hello, " <> ToString[request]|>, "JSON"],
    <|
    "StatusCode" -> 200,
    "ContentType" -> "application/json",
    "Headers" -> { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> origin }
    |>], "HTTPResponse"];
    WriteString[client, response];
    Close[client];
    Print[DateString[] <> " - " <> "Request=" <> ToString[request]];
  ]
 ]
]

url = URLBuild[<|"Scheme" -> "http", 
"Domain" -> First[listener["Socket"]["DestinationIPAddress"]], 
"Port" -> listener["Socket"]["DestinationPort"]|>];

Print["Listening:  ", url, "\n"];
```

And to test in Powershell:

```
PS (Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri http://127.0.0.1:3000?name=kale).Content
```

Should return:

```
{
    "msg":"Hello, kale"
}
```

but exits out as soon as the script finishes executing.

How can I create this socket through WolframScript and keep it running until the script is closed using the new Background & Scheduled Tasks framework in Wolfram Language?

Comment: In version 13.0.1 there is ```ZeroMQLink`PackageScope`$AsyncState``` but it doesn't have the `"Task"` key, so even its `"Status"` key is incorrect because it needs `"Task"`. Although there is ```ZeroMQLink`Loop`PackagePrivate`$backgroundTask``` which seems to be the right one, in my testing on your case, I couldn't respond to the client.

Comment: @BenIzd It does appear to work with `TaskWait`, but yeah, clearly not responding to client. I snooped around quite a bit, but couldn't find that private package. How did you stumble on it?

Comment: ```Names["ZeroMQLink*`*task*", IgnoreCase -> True]``` and also ```"ZeroMQLink*`*async*"```. It's interesting that even using `First@AsynchronousTasks[]` which I think should contain `"Task"` in previous versions, shows the same results (not responding). If you want to explore other possible solutions, you may take a look at [Use function defined in Mathematica from Matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267607/77079) (the Update section). I used a third-party `ZeroMQ` Java library. With some manipulation, you can build your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create this socket through WolframScript and keep it running until the script is closed [...]?

For the server I am using I have this and it seems to do its job well.

```
TaskWait[task = SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask["stayin'alive", 60]]]
```

Comment: Ah. After thinking about it today, I decided to go with `TaskWait[SessionSubmit[While[True, Pause[60]]]]` which is in a similar vein as yours. Not sure if there are any side effects of using `Pause`.

Comment: Yup. `Pause`-while using no CPU time-does seem to gum up the evaluation queue. I'm accepting your answer. Much appreciated.